# I need help formating this data

Tags: python, database, dataframe

I have data like this

```
id,phonenumbers,firstname,lastname,email,birthday,gender,locale,hometown,location,link
```

The problem is some data is not in the format like this

```
000000,000000,name1,name2,email@email,1 1 1990,female,en_En,new york,USA ,new yourk,https://www.example.com
```

As you can see in the "local,hometown" there are 3 commas, I want to delete one of them so the data become like this

```
000000,000000,name1,name2,email@email,1 1 1990,female,en_En ,new york USA, new yourk,https://www.example.com
```

This is just an example to the problem in my data there could be more than 3 commas and different addresses

Essentially I want to load the data into excel and have it show up clean each column with the right data

Comment: Please show the data and your code that you have worked on so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a value is split into multiple colums when it should be in one column. If this is only possible with one column but we have a fixed number of columns before and after, then it's possible to fix it:

```
testdata = "000000,000000,name1,name2,email@email,1 1 1990,female,en_En,new york,USA ,new yourk,https://www.example.com"

def split(data, cols_before_addr=8, cols_after_addr=1):    
    raw_cols = data.split(',')
    return  raw_cols[:cols_before_addr] \
          + ["\n".join(raw_cols[cols_before_addr:-cols_after_addr])] \
          + raw_cols[-cols_after_addr:]

print(split(testdata))
```

Comment: thx it works but in my data i have arabic words and i shows up like this "'ط³ط§ظ„ظ…'"

i tryed changing the encode to UTF-8 but is shows up like this

 "\xd8\xb7\xc2\xb3\xd8\xb7\xc2\xa7\xd8\xb8\xe2\x80\x9e\xd8\xb8\xe2\x80\xa6"